# Prove that $\|Q\mathbf{v}\|=\|\mathbf{v}\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

> Prove that if $Q$ is a real $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix and $\mathbf{v}$ is in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then $$\|Q\mathbf{v}\| = \|\mathbf{v}\|.$$  Be sure to set out your arguments clearly and logically, giving full reasons.

Hello all, 
To solve this do I try and show that $1$ is an eigenvalue? Or is there some rule I'm missing.

Comment: Taking the square on both sides would be a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That wouldn't be enough, since this needs to be true for any $\mathbf{v}$, not just for the eigenvector.  Instead, consider $||Q\mathbf{v}||^2 = \mathbf{v}^T Q^T Q \mathbf{v}$, and see what you'd get.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for all $x$ and $y$ column vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$, one has:
$$\langle x,y\rangle={}^\intercal xy.$$
Therefore, for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, one has:
$$\|Qv\|^2=\langle Qv,Qv\rangle={}^\intercal v{}^\intercal QQv={}^\intercal vv=\|v\|^2,$$
since $Q$ is orthogonal *i.e.* ${}^\intercal QQ=I_n$. Whence the result.

Comment: That was very concrete, thanks a lot